# Java decrementing an integer in an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I am trying to make a program for a video store. When the user hires a video I want the `array` to `-1` from the inStock feild when a hire has been made. How would I search the `array` for the videoID the user entered and remove `1` from the instock feild?

```
// this is my arraylist (Sting videoID, String Title, double Price, int inStock)
videos[0]=new Video("140","The Matrix   ", 7.50,        3);          
videos[1]=new Video("141", "Terminator 2    ", 5.00,        3);
videos[2]=new Video("142", "Shrek       ", 5.00,        10);
```

Comment: Well, there are two tasks there: finding the `Video`, and decrementing the `inStock` field. Once you've done the first, the second should be easy. What have you tried for the first aspect? Also, why are you using strings for the first argument, when they look like they're all just integers?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();

        Video v = new Video();
        v.setVideoId("140");
        v.setPrice(7.50);
        v.setTitle("The Matrix");
        v.setInStock(3);

        videoList.add(v);

        Video v2 = new Video();
        v2.setVideoId("141");
        v2.setPrice(5.00);
        v2.setTitle("The Matrix");
        v2.setInStock(3);

        videoList.add(v2);

        Video v3 = new Video();
        v3.setVideoId("142");
        v3.setPrice(5.00);
        v3.setTitle("Shrek");
        v3.setInStock(10);

        videoList.add(v3);
        String hire = "141";
        int quantity  = 2;
        for(Video video : videoList){
            if(video.getVideoId().equals(hire)){
                if(video.getInStock()>0)
                video.setInStock(video.getInStock() - quantity);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should add a new method to your Video class to update the current stock.

Then use ;

```
videos[<a-value>].updateStock();
```

Or you can simply use a setter to change the value.

```
videos[<a-value>].setStock(<another-value>);
```

However, your model seems to be too simple and not really relevant.
You should create another class to represent an "association table".
Then, you can record a Rent(user_id, video_id, rent_nb, date).

You will be able to track users, to check rent dates, number, etc.

Have nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad idea using Array.

Make `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> videos = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

Now add your videos into ArrayList `videos`.

For example :-

```
ArrayList<String> video = new ArrayList<String>();

video.add("140");
 video.add("Shrek");
 video.add("5");
 video.add(10);
```

Now add this `video` into `videos`

```
videos.add(video);
```

For removing a video do this;

```
for(int i =0; i<videos.size();i++){
   videos.get(i).contains("140");
   videos.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: How about creating a  `Video` class?

Comment: he already has a class Video, so why would you want to make an ArrayList of an ArrayList?

Comment: its gotta be an array its for a tafe assignment